# Overlay for drawer

Tags: objective-c, overlay, drawer

I am implementing drawer in my project. I used SWRevealViewController custom class.Its working fine.But i need to put overlay for front view. While clicking menu icon front view should be black.I want to design overlay like play store.

Comment: Can you please add more information about your requirement?

Comment: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController -Used tis custom class to create drawer.